# Is this patent still active

Tags: patentability

It says filing date 1999 but publication date 2004

Publication number  US6706023 B1
Publication type    Grant
Application number  US 09/454,138
Publication date    Mar 16, 2004
Filing date Dec 3, 1999
Priority date   Dec 3, 1999
Fee status  Paid

Answer (score 1):

USPTO Patent [FAQ](http://www.uspto.gov/main/faq/index.html), [PATENTS - Basic Process](http://www.uspto.gov/main/faq/faq000a.htm#p2), [How long does patent protection last?](http://www.uspto.gov/main/faq/p120013.htm) -

> For applications filed on or after June 8, 1995, utility and plant
>   patents are granted for a term which begins with the date of the grant
>   and usually ends 20 years from the date you first applied for the
>   patent subject to the payment of appropriate maintenance fees. Design
>   patents last 14 years from the date you are granted the patent. Note:
>   Patents in force on June 8 and patents issued thereafter on
>   applications filed prior to June 8, 1995 automatically have a term
>   that is the greater of the twenty year term discussed above or
>   seventeen years from the patent grant.

Patent [US 6706023 B1](http://www.google.com/patents/US6706023) has a filing date of Dec 3, 1999, which is after June 8, 1995. Patent protection would extend to 20 years from the filing date of Dec 3, 1999.